# empty span elements within div block

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like to append updated javascript data to 2 span tags, `rescued` and `rescued2`, when it's available. Since I'm appending new data, I first need to empty out the tags first so they don't keep reappending data...

```
    function updateHUD() {
        $('#bottomDisplay').empty();            
        $('#rescued').append("Total Animals Rescued: " + rescuedTotal_Array.length);
        $('#rescued2').append("Total Animals Rescued lol: " + rescuedTotal_Array.length);                       
    }

    <div id="bottomDisplay">
        <ul>
            <li>Total Animals Rescued: <span id="rescued"></span></li>
            <li>Total Animals Rescued2: <span id="rescued2"></span></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

I'd like to do the clear that way so I don't need to individually `clear` each `span`... but instead clear the entire div block then start over. Instead, when I clear the `div` block, it just erases all spans inside.

Why is this not acceptable?

On another note, I suppose I can just skip the `clearing` and `appending`, and just set the text...

```
    $('#rescued').text(rescuedTotal_Array.length);
    $('#rescued2').text(rescuedTotal_Array.length);
```

Comment: If you concatenate a `<span...` to your data then you can just use `.html()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.empty` gets rid of everything inside the selected element. If you want to empty both spans in one go, you'd need to do:

```
$('#bottomDisplay').find('span').empty();
```

---

For reference, here's what `.empty` looks like:

```
empty: function() {
    var elem,
        i = 0;

    for ( ; (elem = this[i]) != null; i++ ) {
        if ( elem.nodeType === 1 ) {

            // Prevent memory leaks
            jQuery.cleanData( getAll( elem, false ) );

            // Remove any remaining nodes
            elem.textContent = "";
        }
    }

    return this;
}
```

`elem.textContent = "";` is what is getting rid of everything inside.

Comment: Thanks for that... I guess just setting the `text` properties is good enough?

Comment: @Growler For your situation, that would work. My coworker and I were looking through multiple methods of swapping content yesterday and found this jsperf really handy (and somewhat surprising): http://jsperf.com/jquery-html-vs-replacewith/4. The `.text` method is not checked on there, but depending on how often you're updating those spans, it might be worthwhile to have a little more code for a lot more performance.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little confused by the question but I think I understand.  Correct me if I'm not understanding you fully.

You are looking for a single line to empty both spans. However, you want to leave the rest of the HTML inside the div intact and you don't want to have to target each individual span.  The following line would work:

```
$('#bottomDisplay span').empty();
```